# NoSaveStateFrameLayout - Already has a parent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentmanager

I'm attempting to manipulate The fragments remove/add/replace, The problem starts when I try to remove and add again the same fragment class(not same instance).

I clear the entire activity:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < frags.length; i++) {
            BaseFragment fragment = frags[i];
            if (!exsitingFragments.contains(fragment))
                continue;
            FragmentTransaction ft1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft1.detach(fragment);
            ft1.remove(fragment);
            ft1.commit();
            getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        }
```

and add the new instance of the fragments:

```
        for (Object object : fragmentTypes) {
            FragmentTransaction ft2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Class<? extends BaseFragment> fragmentType = (Class<? extends BaseFragment>) object;

            Fragment finalFragment = Tools.createNewInstance(fragmentType);
            ft2.add(parentViewId, finalFragment);
            ft2.commit();
            getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        }
```

This works well for the first time, and also for all the other screens in the application, BUT, when I try to recreate the screen, e.g. call this logic again, remove all the fragments, and add the new instances of these fragments, I get the following error:

```
08-14 15:20:50.086: E/AndroidRuntime(11443): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
08-14 15:20:50.086: E/AndroidRuntime(11443):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3739)
08-14 15:20:50.086: E/AndroidRuntime(11443):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3610)
08-14 15:20:50.086: E/AndroidRuntime(11443):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3586)
08-14 15:20:50.086: E/AndroidRuntime(11443):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:770)
08-14 15:20:50.086: E/AndroidRuntime(11443):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
08-14 15:20:50.086: E/AndroidRuntime(11443):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
08-14 15:20:50.086: E/AndroidRuntime(11443):    at com.mypermissions.core.ui.BaseFragment.onCreateView(BaseFragment.java:83)
08-14 15:20:50.086: E/AndroidRuntime(11443):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
08-14 15:20:50.086: E/AndroidRuntime(11443):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
08-14 15:20:50.086: E/AndroidRuntime(11443):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
08-14 15:20:50.086: E/AndroidRuntime(11443):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-14 15:20:50.086: E/AndroidRuntime(11443):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
08-14 15:20:50.086: E/AndroidRuntime(11443):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
```

Now this is weird since it only happens when the fragment has a ViewPager view in it, in all other cases so far this logic works fine, what weird is that this error is thrown because the **NoSaveStateFrameLayout** already have a parent, and not any other view...

I've tried this:

```
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    rootView.removeAllViews();
```

But after a short debugging, I've found out that there are multiple instances of **NoSaveStateFrameLayout** and removing the one I could was not the same instance as the one causing the exception.

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was adding the same fragment twice, one via xml, and one via code, and in each of these instances, there was another fragment in the xml, for some reason the first time it created the screen the second time failing with that error.